# Is it possible to use Power Query editor and Excel side by side

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

When Power Query editor is opened it does not let me edit, change anything in the opened excel workbooks.

I want to edit an Excel sheet, while working with Power Query Editor. Is it even Possible?Is so how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, every workbook you open or create will run in the same Excel instance. The Power Query window locks all editing of any other Excel interface of the **same Excel instance.** You won't be able to edit the workbook that the query belongs to, while the Power Query window is open.

There is a UserVoice item asking for this functionality. Cast your vote here. https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/19005490-allow-interaction-with-excel-while-in-power-query

You can, however, open a new instance of Excel, which will not be affected by the Power Query window. To open a new instance, right click the Excel icon on the task bar, hold down the ALT key, click the Excel command icon and then click yes in the dialog.

[image]

Comment: It took me a few goes to get this. You need to hold down the Alt key until the confirmation dialog box appears.